# If Not RS.EOF and Not RS.BOF then written for ADODB versus current DAO format

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have use of If Not RS.EOF and Not RS.BOF is a DAO Recordset, but I cannot use DAO in the new SQL backend environment. Code is as follows:

```vbs
Function CloseSession()
'This closes the open session

Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Tbl_LoginSessions WHERE fldLoginKey =" & LngLoginId)

If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then
    Rs.Edit
    Rs.Fields("fldLogoutEvent").Value = Now()
    Rs.Update
    Rs.Close
End If

Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Users] WHERE PKUserID =" & LngUserID)

'Flag user as being logged out
    If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then
        Rs.Edit
        Rs.Fields("fldLoggedIn").Value = 0
        Rs.Fields("FldComputer").Value = ""
        Rs.Update
        Rs.Close
    End If
Set Rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Essentially, I have started to write the code in ADODB.  However, upon researching If Not RS.EOF topic on the internet for ADODB, I was utterly unsuccessful. Does someone have knowledge on the utilization RS.EOF and RS.BOF that could be helpful in my plight to rewrite?

```vbs
Function CloseSession()

'/This closes the open session
'/Define the OLE DB connection string.
StrConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbswd0027;UID=Mickey01;PWD=Mouse02;DATABASE=Regulatory;"

'/Instantiate the Connection object and open a database connection.
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.Open StrConnectionString

Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim StrLoginName As String
Dim StrComputerName As String

'/passing variables
StrComputerName = FindComputerName
strLoggedIn = "False"

'/Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
 strSQL1 = "Update tTbl_LoginSessions SET fldLogoutEvent = '" & Now() & "'" & _
 " WHERE fldLoginKey = " & LngLoginId

'/Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
 strSQL2 = "Update tTbl_LoginUsers SET fldLoggedIn = '" & strLoggedIn & "', fldComputer = '" & StrComputerName & "'" & _
 " WHERE intCPIIUserID = " & LngUserID

cnn.Execute strSQL1, , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
cnn.Execute strSQL2, , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
'/close connections and clean up
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: `If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then` is also valid for ADO (though typically just checking EOF is sufficient)

Comment: SQL Server may not accept the date time stirng from '" & Now() & "', you shall convert it in format, for example, 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my answer:

```
Function LogMeIn(sUser As Long)
' was Function LogMeIn()
'/Go to the users table and record that the user has logged in
'/and which computer they have logged in from

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'/Dim sUser As Long
Dim strComputerName As String, strLoggedIn As String

'passing variables
strLoggedIn = "True"
strComputerName = FindComputerName()


 'Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
  strSQL = "Update dbo.tTbl_LoginUsers SET fldLoggedIn = '" & strLoggedIn & "',      fldComputer = '" & strComputerName & "'" & _
 " WHERE intCPIIUserID = " & sUser
Debug.Print strSQL
'connect to SQL Server
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con
    .ConnectionString = cSQLConn
    .Open
End With

'write back
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
    'Debug.Print strSQL
End With

'close connections
con.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In the DAO case your code is using (DAO) Recordset objects and avoiding explicit SQL statements; in the ADO case you're using explicit SQL statements and avoiding using (ADO) Recordset objects. As such, the short answer to your question is: use ADO Recordset objects, and you will have your `BOF` and `EOF` properties like with DAO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As an aside, you're also using late binding in the ADO case, and I'd suggest you use early binding instead (i.e., add a reference to the ADO type library and use strongly not weakly typed object variables).

That said, in the DAO Recordset case you usually get an instance of it by calling a `Database` object's `OpenRecordset` method; in contrast, you instantiate the ADO version directly before calling its `Open` method, usually passing in an ADO `Connection` object (an ADO `Connection` roughly corresponds to a DAO `Database`). There's also no explicit `Edit` method:

```
Dim Connection As New ADODB.Connection, RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Connection.Open StrConnectionString
RS.Open "SELECT * FROM Tbl_LoginSessions WHERE fldLoginKey =" & LngLoginId,
    Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockPessimistic
If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then
    Rs.Fields("fldLogoutEvent").Value = Now() '!!!though see jacouh's comment
    Rs.Update
    Rs.Close
End If

RS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Users] WHERE PKUserID =" & LngUserID,
    Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockPessimistic
'Flag user as being logged out
If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then
    Rs.Fields("fldLoggedIn").Value = 0
    Rs.Fields("FldComputer").Value = ""
    Rs.Update
    Rs.Close
End If
```

Comment: @ Chris Rolliston and Jacouh both of your comments are very helpful. In the spirit of using the RS option provided by Chris and learning more about it, I am now running into a Run-time error '3705': Operation is not allowed when the object is open. I tried debugging line by line, but to no avail I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to test this, I've compiled, but not run it as I've not created such tables in db:

```
Function CloseSession()

'/This closes the open session
'/Define the OLE DB connection string.
  Dim LngLoginId, LngUserID
  Dim nDone
  Dim StrConnectionString
  Dim strSQL1 As String
  Dim strSQL2 As String
  Dim strLoggedIn As String
  Dim StrLoginName As String
  Dim StrComputerName As String

  Dim cnn

  StrConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbswd0027;UID=Mickey01;PWD=Mouse02;DATABASE=Regulatory;"

'/Instantiate the Connection object and open a database connection.
  Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  cnn.Open StrConnectionString

'/passing variables
' StrComputerName = FindComputerName
  StrComputerName = Environ("COMPUTERNAME")

  LngLoginId = 58
  LngUserID = 38
  strLoggedIn = "False"

'/Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
   strSQL1 = "UPDATE tTbl_LoginSessions" _
     & " SET fldLogoutEvent = '" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss") & "'" & _
     " WHERE fldLoginKey = " & LngLoginId

'/Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
   strSQL2 = "UPDATE tTbl_LoginUsers" _
     & " SET fldLoggedIn = '" & strLoggedIn & "'" _
     & ", fldComputer = '" & StrComputerName & "'" & _
     " WHERE intCPIIUserID = " & LngUserID

  cnn.Execute strSQL1, nDone
  cnn.Execute strSQL2, nDone
'/close connections and clean up
  cnn.Close
  Set cnn = Nothing
'
End Function
```

RS.EOF is not used here, as we use a direct update.

Answer (score 0):

"If Not Rs.EOF And Not Rs.BOF Then" is a way of seeing if the recordset is empty or not. Only when the recordset is empty can Rs.BOF and Rs.EOF both be true.